# Domain delegation problema in EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I'm having trouble to delegate my domain .com.ar (Argentina) with my EC2 instance in AWS (Amazon). I've already set the 4 Amazon DNS in the domain panel but it doesn't work. Any advice?
Thanks, regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In DNS zone file create A record of EIP. This will directly point your domain to AWS Instance.

Comment: Thank you, that's the thing was missing. Now, I have my domain working. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm breaking this into a new answer as I can't easily format my comments above.

Your domain whois record is here: http://whois.marcaria.com/domain-whois/south-america/argentina?q=pediloya.com.ar

The 'Nameservers' in your whois record don't appear to be set to Route53, they're still set to the following:

```
Name Servers 
athea.ar. 200.16.98.2 
ctina.ar. 200.16.97.17 
merapi.switch.ch. 130.59.211.10
2001:620:0:0:0:0:0:5 
ns.uu.net. 137.39.1.3 
ns1.retina.ar. 200.10.202.3 
ns-ar.ripe.net. 193.0.12.11 
uucp-gw-1.pa.dec.com. 204.123.2.18 
uucp-gw-2.pa.dec.com. 204.123.2.19
```

You will need to use your domain management tools at your registrar to change these to the 4 nameservers Route53 provides (and remove all of the above).

To check if the nameserver is responding for the domain you can use dig, eg:

```
dig @nameserver pediloya.com.ar
```

Replace "nameserver" with one of the 4 Route53 has assigned to you, eg:

Answer (score 0):

I have used the command you told me..:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52263
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pediloya.com.ar.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pediloya.com.ar.        300     IN      A       54.148.14.187

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pediloya.com.ar.        172800  IN      NS      ns-1431.awsdns-50.org.
pediloya.com.ar.        172800  IN      NS      ns-1565.awsdns-03.co.uk.
pediloya.com.ar.        172800  IN      NS      ns-325.awsdns-40.com.
pediloya.com.ar.        172800  IN      NS      ns-655.awsdns-17.net.
```

Comment: This means the AWS part is configured correctly, route53 is responding fine. As I mentioned previously you need to change your nameservers at the registrar level, the place you purchased pediloya.com.ar.